# How can I access the methods of one class from another class in a different folder in Java?

Tags: java, import, package

I have two folders: `FolderA` & `FolderB` that contain java files `ProgramA.java` & `ProgramB.java` respectively.

`ProgramA.java` contains a `main` method and `ProgramB.java` does not have any `main` method, also `FolderA` & `FolderB` are both contained in the same parent folder.

**Question:** What would I do if I would like to access some of the methods in `ProgramB.java` from `ProgramA.java`?

All help is appreciated! :)

//ProgramA in FolderA

```
import packageB.*;
public class ProgramA {
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("Hello World");
 }
}
```

//ProgramB in FolderB

```
package packageB;
public class ProgramB {
 public static void print() {
  System.out.println("GoodBye World");
 }
}
```

When I try to compile `ProgramA` I get the following error:

> ProgramA.java:1: error: package packageB does not exist

Comment: Add folder B as a source to folder A.

Comment: post your code and what you tried so far.

Comment: Define FolderA and FolderB as packages and import FolderA package in ProgramB! Then declare a object of ProgramA in ProgramB and then you can access its methods!

Comment: @minc33 : Is your package name for both the java files is correct ?